# How to set display block to an object based on count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a booking flight form that takes the count of childs travellers.

There are 3 `select` to define the age of each travel but I set `display:none` to them.

I wrote the below code but I don't know how can I show each `select` based on each time that I add a number for each travel.

For example, when the user add 1 travel, I want to show the first `select`. 2 show the second `select`.

I want to show each `select` based on increment and decrement of the value with classname `travel`.

How can I do this ?

Here is my snippet :

```js
  $(function() {
  $(".button-click a").on("click", function() {
    var button = $(this);
    var oldVal = parseInt(button.closest("ul").prev().val());
    var newVal = (button.text() == "+") ? oldVal+1: (oldVal > 0) ? oldVal-1 : 0;
    var total_value = "";
    
    button.closest("ul").prev().val(newVal);

    $(".travel").each(function(){
      var cat = $(this).prev('span').text();
      total_value += cat + ": " + $(this).val() + ", "; 
    });
    
    total_value = total_value.substring(0, total_value.length - 2);
    $(".main").val(total_value);
  })
})
```

```css
.childs{ display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
Count all1 Traveller(s)
<input type="text" name="no_travellers" class="main" value="Adults: 1" placeholder="" />
</label>
<br/>
<label>
   <span>Children</span>
   <input type="text" class="travel" id="CAT_Custom_410672" name="CAT_Custom_410672"  value="0" />
   <ul class="button-group button-click">
      <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-plus"><span class="hide">+</span></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-minus"><span class="hide">-</span></i></a></li>
   </ul>
</label>
<div class="childs">
   <label>Child1</label>
   <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="childs">
   <label>Child2</label>
   <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one of many possible ways to do it. Basically what you want is to:

1. Create a generic function which can generate the necessary markup for a child dropdown when the number of children increases. Let's call it `createChildDropdown(i)`

   - This function will receive an index (the new child count), so that we can generate unique fields with unique IDs
2. Create a generic function which can remove a generated child dropdown when the number of children decreases. Let's call it `destroyChildDropdown($el, i)`

   - This function will again receive an index (the new child count), so that we can remove the correct child dropdown
   - It also receives a jQuery selector so it knows from which element to remove the child dropdown from

Now that we have the logic in place, we can simply check the `newVal` vs the `oldVal` to know if the number of children has increased or not, and call the correct functions. Assuming that we create a new element called `<div class="childDropdowns">` to hold all your dropdowns, we can do this:

```
if (oldVal < newVal) {
  $('.childDropdowns').append(createChildDropdown(newVal));
} else if (oldVal > newVal) {
  destroyChildDropdown($('.childDropdowns'), newVal);
}
```

```js
$(function() {

  // Function to create child dropdown
  var createChildDropdown = function(i) {
  
    // Create a div in the following format:
    // <div class="childs">
    //    <label for="...">Child (number)</label>
    //    <select id="..."></select>
    // </div>
    var $childDropdown = $('<div />', {
      'class': 'childs'
    });
    $childDropdown.append($('<label />', {
      'for': 'childDropdown-' + i
    }).text('Child ' + i));
    $childDropdown.append($('<select />', {
      'id': 'childDropdown-' + i
    }));
    
    // Define options made available for each child
    var options = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    options.forEach(function(option) {
      // Create new option element and append to <select>
      $childDropdown.find('select').append($('<option />').text(option).attr('value', option));
    });
    
    // Return documentFragment so that we can append it
    return $childDropdown;
  };
  
  // Function to destroy child dropdown
  var destroyChildDropdown = function($el, i) {
    $el.find('div.childs').get(i).remove();
  };

  $(".button-click a").on("click", function() {
    var button = $(this);
    var oldVal = parseInt(button.closest("ul").prev().val());
    var newVal = (button.text() == "+") ? oldVal + 1 : (oldVal > 0) ? oldVal - 1 : 0;
    var total_value = "";

    button.closest("ul").prev().val(newVal);

    $(".travel").each(function() {
      var cat = $(this).prev('span').text();
      total_value += cat + ": " + $(this).val() + ", ";
    });

    if (oldVal < newVal) {
      $('.childDropdowns').append(createChildDropdown(newVal));
    } else if (oldVal > newVal) {
      destroyChildDropdown($('.childDropdowns'), newVal);
    }

    total_value = total_value.substring(0, total_value.length - 2);
    $(".main").val(total_value);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
Count all1 Traveller(s)
<input type="text" name="no_travellers" class="main" value="Adults: 1" placeholder="" />
</label>
<br/>
<label>
   <span>Children</span>
   <input type="text" class="travel" id="CAT_Custom_410672" name="CAT_Custom_410672"  value="0" />
   <ul class="button-group button-click">
      <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-plus"><span class="hide">+</span></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-minus"><span class="hide">-</span></i></a></li>
   </ul>
</label>
<div class="childDropdowns"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. my question is : how can i set name to each selectbox ?another question is can i send this selectbox values with form ?

Comment: @inaz If you want to set the `name` attribute, look into the `createChildDropdown()` function and in the part where the `<select>` element is created and appended, you can add `'name': 'childDropdown-' + i`, or anything that you fancy. Just remember the name has to be unique so that each child will have his select value stored. As long as these elements are injected as a child of a `<form>` element, they will be sent with the form.

Comment: i face with a problem . i need to send different values . but in this function we dont have anything to put the value on each option. in each selectbox i want to start values of each option from 0 to 12. how can i do this?

Comment: @inaz Did you read the comments in the code? Just modify the array in `var option = [...]`

Comment: i want to change the value of each option . in this case the text and the value are the same for example :<option value="0">a</option> i need to change the 0